# Форматирование вывода чисел C#

Tags: c#

По заданию нужно 
Одномерный массив сжать, удалив из него все элементы, величина которых находится в интервале [a, b].
Освободившиеся в конце элемента массива заполнить нулями.

Вот код

```
using System;

namespace Massiv6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Ведите размерность массива n = ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double[] mas = new double[n];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
            {
                mas[i] = rand.NextDouble() * 200 - 100;
            }
            ShowMassiv(mas, "Исходный массив: ");

        Console.Write("Ведите a = ");
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ведите b = ");
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        CompressMassiv(ref mas, a, b);
        ShowMassiv(mas, "Сжатый массив: ");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Вывести массив
    static void ShowMassiv(double[] mas, string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("{0:#.##} ", mas[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //Сжать массив, удалив из него все элементы, величина которых находится в интервале [a, b].
    //Освободившиеся в конце элемента массива заполнить нулями.
    static void CompressMassiv(ref double[] mas, double a, double b)
    {
        if (b < a)
        {
            double temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (mas[i] <= a || mas[i] >= b)
            {
                ++k;
            }
        }

        double[] tempMas = new double[k];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (mas[i] <= a || mas[i] >= b)
            {
                tempMas[count] = mas[i];
                ++count;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i < k)
            {
                mas[i] = tempMas[i];
            }
            else
            {
                mas[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Не могу понять, почему к исходному массиву метод вывода ShowMassiv со строкой

```
Console.Write("{0:#.##} ", mas[i]);
```

применяется и всё выводится, а к сжатому массиву, в котором числа в конце заменены нулями, нет, и эти нули не выводятся, хотя они в массиве есть, и функция ShowMassiv работает правильно и выводит весь массив с нулями целиком только если задать

```
Console.Write("{0:f2} ", mas[i]);
```

?

Comment: Используйте формат "{0:0.00}" будут выводиться ваши нули, правда и строка будет достраиввться нулями. Т.е. будет формат 1.00 и 1.20. Если нули в конце не нужны используйте 0.##

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку # будет выводить цифру только в случае если она есть, а f2 фиксирует вывод с 2я знаками после запятой.

Всё согласно документации.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: А почему тогда форматирование #.## не срабатывает, если приравнивать `mas[i] = 0.00;` ?

Comment: Что значит "не срабатывает"? (0.00).ToString("#.##") дает пустую строку, как и положено.